# Robocopy backup with date added BUT don't copy if you already have the files

Tags: robocopy

I have found several posts about adding the date stamp to a backup but what I would like to do goes a bit beyond that. My situation is as follows:

Weekly we do manual backups of software apps, databases, alarms, events and such. The day of the week the backup occurs on could vary. So I created a robocopy batch file that copies from my source to my destination like so:

Robocopy "source" "destination" /S /E /ZB /R:10 /W:5 /V /ETA /LOG+:c:\log.text

I would like to add the timestamp to the destination, but since this is scheduled to run daily, I really only want a copy when the files change. Since I cannot predict the day the backup gets run, I have chosen daily but can't figure out how to still separate the backups by date, while not taking a copy everyday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[/XO](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

> eXclude Older - if destination file exists and is the same date or newer than the source - don’t bother to overwrite it.

Comment: I will give it a shot and check this off as the answer if this does the trick. Thanks for the suggestion.